# ANOVA of GLM with paired and unpaired data

Tags: anova, paired-data

I am a master student doing an intersnship on homeranges of domestic cats.
Our data has somes individuals in 3 locations and we have a few females and males every time. For each individuals, we have sometime 1, sometime 2, sometime 3 and sometime the whole 4 seasons but it depends. It seems that my data is paired and not paired, with missing links.

There is 60 observations approx. and the data are factors for sex/season/location and numeric for homerange. The data come from GPS locations that have been transformed into home ranges through MCP and AKDE models (calabrese 2016). Some cats have been followed 1 seasons, some 2 some 3 and some 4 so 1 cat can have different season (and different numeric response for each season) but no different sex or location.

We are trying to do ANOVA of the GLM (gamma family) of the homeranges with site * sex * location in the model.

Can we do the GLM and can we apply the ANOVA when some of the data is paired and some is not with some missing links in the "paired" between seasons?

Comment: This could be an interesting question but you need to tell us (much) more about the data. Maybe you can show us a small excerpt? How many observations? How was the data obtained?

Comment: There is 60 observations approx. and the data are factors for sex/season/location and numeric for homerange. The data come from GPS locations that have been transformed into home ranges through MCP and AKDE models (calabrese 2016). Some cats have been followed 1 seasons, some 2 some 3 and some 4 so 1 cat can have different season (and different numeric response) but no different sex or location.

Comment: Could you please add that new information as an edit to the post?